# Is there a way to rewrite this equations in terms of k?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Is there a way to rewrite the equation $$\frac{(m+n)^2+m+3n}{2}$$ in terms of $k \geq 0$ where $k=m+n$?

I'm trying to find the values taken by $$C(m,n)= \frac{(m+n)^2+m+3n}{2}$$ when $(m,n) $is described by $D_k$ = {$(m,n)$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}^2, m+n = k$}, which might be useful to show if $C$ is injective or surjective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can rewrite the expression as:
$$\frac{k^2+k+2n}{2}$$
Now notice that we can keep $k$ fixed and vary $n$, by setting $m=k-n$. By considering simple examples, like $m=0,n=1$ and $m=1,n=0$, we can see that the value of the expression depends on more than just the value of $k$, so we can't write it just in terms of $k$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, expressions involving $m,n$ can be converted into expressions containing $m+n$ and $m-n$ both, but not involving only one of $m+n$ and $m-n$. [Exceptions are when entire expression contains only one of $m+n$, $m-n$ e.g, $(m+n)^3-5m-5n$  ]. This is because of the following linear combination, which says $m$ and $n$ are made of both parts:

$$m=\frac{m+n}{2}+\frac{m-n}{2}$$
$$n=\frac{m+n}{2}-\frac{m-n}{2}$$

$m+n$ is called the symmetric part and $m-n$ is the antisymmetric part. These two are independent of each other (or orthogonal).

So setting $k=m+n$, $l=m-n$,
$$(m+n)^2+m+3n = k^2 + k + 2n $$
$$\boxed{(m+n)^2+m+3n = k^2 + 2k - l} $$